# Multiple equations of a system on one line

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, systeme, horizontal

I tried to write a system with multiple equations on every line.
I have this:

And I have the following error:
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Could you please help?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a fill compilable code, not a screenshot?

Comment: The problem here is that `cases` accepts a `<case> & <when>` style input, where multiple lines are separated by ``\\``. You have more than the above. That is, more than one `&` per line. This is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest an `aligned` environment in  `cases`. I used `dcases` from `mathtools` to have the contents in `\displaystyle`.

Beware that for multicolumn aligned equations, each column but the first has to be introduced by an ampersand, in addition to the ampersands for the alignment points, so that here (4 columns), we need `7&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}\;
    \begin{aligned}% {4}
    u' & =k_{1}a, & a' & = -k_{1}u, \\
    u' & =k_{2}u^{2}v, & v' & =-k_{2}u^{2} v, \\
    v' & =k_{3}ub, & d' & =k_{3}ub ,& b' & =-k_{3}bu, & u' & =-k_{3}bu, \\
    e' & =k_{4}u, & u' & = -k_{4}u. 
     \end{aligned}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]